# Корректное завершение скрипта

Tags: perl

Есть парсер на перл. Для загрузки страниц использую библиотеку `LWP::Simple`.
Когда происходит загрузка страницы, при недоступности ресурса, возникает такая ошибка:

> Error GETing http://...: Status read failed: Соединение сброшено другой стороной
> В результате скрипт аварийно завершается.

Хотелось бы узнать, как эту проблему устранить или как обработать данную ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eval {
    # Запрос тут.
};
if ($@) {
    # Обработка ошибки тут.
    # Ошибка в $@.
}
```

Или

```
use Try::Tiny;

try {
    # Запрос тут.
}
catch {
    # Обработка ошибки тут.
    # Ошибка в $_.
};
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Все заработало как нужно.

Comment: это не решает проблему. antonio, покажите ваш код в месте где вызывается функция get.

Comment: Вот код метода:
<pre>

sub get_page
{
 my $self = shift;
 my $url = shift;
 
 print "URL:" . $url . "\n";
 eval {
         $self->mechanize(@_)->get($url);
 };
 if ($@){
     print "ERROR GET PAGE\n";
     $self->add_error('NOT_AVAILABLE', $@);
     return '';
 }
 
 if( exists$self->{_CONFIG}->{page_timeout} ){
  sleep($self->{_CONFIG}->{page_timeout});
 }
 
 if( $self->mechanize(@_)->success ){
  return $self->mechanize(@_)->content();
 }
 
 return '';
}

</pre>
и он нормально работает сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь `LWP::UserAgent`

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response  = $ua->get('http://....');
if ($response->is_success) {
  my $data = $response->content;
  # обработка данных
} else {
  # обработка ошибки
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Если вы используете функцию get, то она должна возвращать значение в случае удачного запроса и undef в случае неудачи. Другими словами:

```
my $response = get ( 'http://some.url/' );
if ( $response )
{
   # обработать информацию, возвращенную по запросу
}
else 
{
   # действия, в случае неудачного ответа
}
```

PS: Выдержка из perldoc LWP::Simple специально для минусующих:

> The get() function will
> fetch the document identified by the
> given   URL and return it.  It returns
> "undef" if it fails.

Другими словами, если использовать конструкцию типа

```
my $date = get ( $someUrl ) or die $!;
```

то скипт будет умирать каждый раз, когда запрос будет завешраться неудаче.